# One-hot encoding R

Tags: r

I am working on a neural network for the first time, and I am attempting to convert "Ratings" to numeric as a one-hot variable. However, I am unsure how to do this correctly or implement this into my model. As you can see, Ratings ranges from 1-3 and I managed to make Ratings binary by:

```
 data <- data %>% mutate(Ratings_1 = ifelse(Ratings=='1', 1, 0),
          Ratings_2 = ifelse(Ratings=='2', 1, 0),
          Ratings_3 = ifelse(Ratings=='3', 1, 0))
```

As you can see, Ratings ranges from 1-3. I would like this to somehow be binary, but with keeping the ratings 1-3.

I am now wondering how to turn Ratings_1,Ratings_2,Ratings_3 into one numeric variable (Ratings, but now binary with three different options) so I can use this as my dependent variable or if this is even necessary in a neural network? The goal of my NN is to predict the Rating class in the Mobile Games data (“Low” ratings or “High”). I apologize if this question is abstract. I am very new to NN.

```
structure(list(AUR = c(4, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3), URC = c(3553, 
284, 8376, 190394, 28, 47), Price = c(2.99, 1.99, 0, 0, 2.99, 
0), Size = c(15853568, 12328960, 674816, 21552128, 34689024, 
48672768), HasSubtitle = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), InAppSum = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.99), InAppMin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.99), InAppMax = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.99), InAppCount = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), InAppAvg = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.99), descriptionTermCount = c(263, 204, 97, 272, 
365, 368), LanguagesCount = c(17, 1, 1, 17, 15, 1), EngSupported = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), GenreCount = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), months = c(7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7), monthsSinceUpdate = c(29, 17, 25, 29, 15, 6), 
GameFree = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Ratings = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
3), Ratings_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Ratings_2 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0), Ratings_3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

data <- dff
data2 <- mutate_if(data, is.factor,as.numeric) 
data3 <- lapply(data2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
data <- data.frame(data3)

data <- data %>% mutate(Ratings_1 = ifelse(Ratings=='1', 1, 0),
          Ratings_2 = ifelse(Ratings=='2', 1, 0),
          Ratings_3 = ifelse(Ratings=='3', 1, 0))

data$ID <- NULL
data$AgeRating <- NULL
n <- neuralnet(Ratings~AUR+URC+Price+Size+HasSubtitle+InAppSum+InAppMin+InAppMax
           +InAppCount+InAppAvg+descriptionTermCount+LanguagesCount+EngSupported+GenreCount
           +months+monthsSinceUpdate+GameFree,
           data = data,
           hidden = c(5,2),
           startweights = NULL,
           linear.output = F,
           lifesign = 'full',
           rep=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `max.col` function:

```
dat$Ratings <- max.col(dat[,startsWith(names(dat),"Ratings")])
dat  

   Ratings1 Ratings2 Ratings3 Ratings
1         1        0        0       1
2         1        0        0       1
3         1        0        0       1
4         1        0        0       1
5         0        1        0       2
6         0        1        0       2
7         0        1        0       2
8         1        0        0       1
9         0        0        1       3
10        0        0        1       3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Ratings1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Ratings2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), Ratings3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: I always forget Mr `max.col`, that's much better! I delete mine, leaving you my sample data as a gift.

Comment: @onyambu , your code only turned my "Results" column to 1. As mentioned above, the code I created divides "Results" into "Results_1, Results_2...". My goal is have a binary "Results" function that allows me to implement it as a dependent variable.

Comment: @Hi2736464 how many colums do you  have that matches the Ratings? Eg if you run `ncol(dat[,startsWith(names(dat),"Ratings")])` what do you get?. Also probably the first col is all 1 in your data

Comment: @onyambu I only have one Ratings column that ranges from 1-3. For example, Ratings might = 1 and for another game = 3

Comment: @Hi2736464 i answered the opposite. Try`model.matrix(~Ratings - 1, data)` let me know whether that helps